# Getting -MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"- when deploying with Railway

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I know there are other similar questions, but nothing worked for me.

When I host locally, it works, but I get the error with Railway. The full error message is: `MongooseError: The 'uri' parameter to 'openUri() must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to 'mongoose.connect()' or 'mongoose.createConnection()' is a string.`

I have my URI string as `MONGO_URI="mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.jju88.mongodb.net/<collection>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"` inside of a `.env` file. The `.env` file was inside a `config` folder, but somewhere else it said to put it in the root. So I changed it, but it didn't help.

I tried `require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" })` and `require("dotenv").config()` in the server.js file at the top. Before I changed `.env` to the root, it was `require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/.env" })`

The DB config looks like so:

```
    const connectDB = async () => {
      try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useCreateIndex: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
          useFindAndModify: false,
        });
    
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
      }
    };
```

And I have `dotenv` installed as a dependency.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `MONGO_URI` as a variable on Railway.
Variable name = `MONGO_URI`
Value = `mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@CLUSTERNAME.san3z5m.mongodb.net/DBNAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: It's been a while, but for anybody reading it, that was it. Thank you